# Android NDK/JNI undefined reference to function when using C Code

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am having trouble building c-code when using Android Studio NDK/JNI.
What i am basically trying to achieve is, to run c-code which is split into multiple header and source files. To get an easy-to-understand example of what i am trying to achieve, i used here simple c-code which performs a addition (Add.c) and c-code which calls the "add"-Function with defined values (getNumber.c). I would like to use the JNI to just simply call the getNumber() Function in getNumber.c. Everytime i try to build the code i get the Error in calc-lib.c:

> error: undefined reference to 'getNumber()'

In the cpp folder i have the standard "native-lib.cpp".
I added my source files Add.c and getNumber.c and corresponding header files:

Add.c

```
#include "Add.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int addition(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Add.h

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_Add_H
#define APPLICATION_Add_H
int addition(int x, int y);
#endif //APPLICATION_Add_H
```

getNumber.c

```
#include "Add.h"
#include "getNumber.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int getNumber(void){
    return addition(5,5);
}
```

getNumber.h

```
#ifndef MY_APPLICATION_GETNUMBER_H
#define MY_APPLICATION_GETNUMBER_H
int getNumber(void);
#endif //MY_APPLICATION_GETNUMBER_H
```

The correspodning file for JNI, calc-lib.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "getNumber.h"
jint Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_getNumber(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    return  getNumber();
}
```

And the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project("myapplication")
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    native-lib
    SHARED
    native-lib.cpp
    )
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    calc-lib
    SHARED
    calc-lib.c
    getNumber.c
    Add.c
    )
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
    log-lib
    log )
target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    ${log-lib} )
target_link_libraries(
    calc-lib
    Add
    getNumber
    ${log-lib} )
```

I already tried to find solutions and came to the conclusion that it is most likely a linking problem. I tried modifiying the native-lib.cpp file, instead of using a seperate calc-lib.c file to call the getNumber() Function. I aswell tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159183/android-ndk-jni-undefined-reference-to-function-defined-in-custom-header-fil/22159368) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376444/getting-error-undefined-reference-to-function-android-ndk)

If someone has any idea of what i am doing wrong, i would really appreciate some help.

Greetings

vki

Comment: Why do you have `Add` and `getNumber` in `target_link_libraries` for the `calc-lib` target? As far as I can see, you don't have any `Add` or `getNumber` libraries; you have a couple of source files named Add.c and getNumber.c which are part of `calc-lib`.

Comment: I am stupid! Thanks alot! That did it.